# What does "unsexy skills" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "unsexy skills" mean in following sentence?

Tackle the unsexy skills that are rarely addressed but highly important for transitioning into a professional setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In America, "sexy" can be used to mean fashionable, desirable, exciting; not just to describe a person, but almost anything.  So what they are saying when they speak of "unsexy skills" is those skills that are not glamorous, fun to learn or well-publicized, but which are basic to doing well in the profession. The boring stuff; the grunt work. The tedious minutia that keeps the cogs of industry turning.